# how to parse json to keys value pair using scala

Tags: scala

I have this json

```
{
  "config_values": {
    "memory": "4g",
    "cores": "2",
    "max": "2",
    "min": "1"
  }
}
```

I want to use this json to set config, this config_value json will have many values, want to set it

eg.
this is done at this moment

```
config.set("memory","4g").set("cores", "2").set("max", "2")
```

but i want to make it as key- value

```
| keys   | values |
-------------------
| memory | 4g     |
| cores  | 2      |
| max    | 2      |
| min    | 1      |
```

i want to implement this in scala

```
for( i <- 1 to 4){
  config.set(keys(i),values(i))
}
```

Comment: What’s wrong with map?

Comment: Are you using any libraries? It can be easily achieved with [config](https://github.com/lightbend/config).

Comment: @yog Do you want Map from this JSON? Sorry, I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this, I think you are looking for this.

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._

object Demo extends App {

  case class ConfigValues(memory: String, cores: String, max: String, min: String)

  case class Config(config_values: ConfigValues)

  val configJson =
    """{
    "config_values": {
      "memory": "4g",
      "cores": "2",
      "max": "2",
      "min": "1"
    }
  }"""


  def jsonStrToMap(jsonStr: String): Map[String, Any] = {
    implicit val formats: DefaultFormats.type = org.json4s.DefaultFormats
    parse(jsonStr).extract[Map[String, Any]]
  }

  val values = jsonStrToMap(configJson).getOrElse("config_values", Map("" -> "")).asInstanceOf[Map[String, String]]

  values.map { kv =>
    //Set your config here
    //config.set(keys(kv._1),values(kv._2))
    print(kv._1, kv._2)
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks Raman Mishra, I was not able to use map properly, but your solution helped me, workings as expected